# Why am I not getting a missing return statement when while(true) is declared directly meanwhile while(isValid=true) will get missing return error?

Tags: java, while-loop, return

I have a method that returns an integer. I declared boolean variable in while loop. The problem is, I get an error even though I already have a return statement.

"missing return statement"

```
 public static int test() {
        boolean isValid = true;
        while(isValid) { // isValid will return missing error statement
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            try {
                isValid = false;
                return s.nextInt();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                s.next();
                System.out.println("Please enter number through 0 - 9");
            }
        }
          // return 0; no error if not commented
     }
```

Meanwhile, I'm not getting missing return error if I declared the while directly into true.

"no error"

```
private static int getInt() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer ");
        //boolean isValid = true;
        while(true) {
            try {
                return s.nextInt();
            } catch(InputMismatchException e) {
                // go round again.  Read past the end of line in the input first
                s.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please enter a number using only the digits 0 to 9 ");
            }
        }
    }
```

Can anyone explain this to me? This is kind of confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can't be 100% sure for the first code snippet, but it can for the second.

The compiler knows that a `while(true)` loop never stops unless with `return` or `break`. And it sees that there is only a `return` inside the loop, so it knows that the while loop either not finishes, or the method returns. This is fine.

On the other hand, the compiler doesn't know when a `while(isValid)` loop will stop - it doesn't know when `isValid` will be false. Can't it just check for `isValid = false`? Well, you can set `isValid` in lots of other ways, can't you? You can set it to another variable that is false, you can set it to a complex boolean expression that depends on multiple variables, which eventually evaluates to `false`... Are you saying that the compiler should statically analyse the values of all those variables? That's too hard, (if not impossible) for the compiler to do, so it just doesn't bother.

There's also a case that the compiler cannot handle at all. What if `isValid` gets set from another thread?

This is why the compiler asks you to just add a return statement right at the end there, just in case the while loop exits without hitting the `return` inside the while loop.